# Controls inside tabs not showing in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

My problem is probably a quite naive one; anyway I am a little bit confused with PyQt's proper arrangement and displaying of controls inside a tabbed control (tabWidget).

Here is my test code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class tabdemo(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
        super(tabdemo, self).__init__()
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1,"Form View")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2,"Matrix View")
        self.tab1UI()
        self.tab2UI()
        self.setWindowTitle("tab demo")

   def tab1UI(self):
        l1 = QListView()
        l2 = QListView()
        model = QStringListModel()        
        model.setStringList(QString("Item 1;Item 2;Item 3;Item 4").split(";"))    
        l1.setModel(model)
        l2.setModel(model)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(l1)
        hbox.addStretch()
        hbox.addWidget(l2) 
        self.tab1.setLayout(hbox)

   def tab2UI(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        tbl1 = QTableWidget()
        tbl1.setRowCount(5)
        tbl1.setColumnCount(5)
        vbox.addWidget(tbl1)
        tbl1.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("1")) # row, col
        self.tab2.setLayout(vbox)

def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = tabdemo()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

When I run it, I get the main form displayed, but nothing appears inside it. However, if I create the form as a direct descendant of QTabWidget (instead of QMainWindow) it runs OK, with all tabs and controls contained therein correctly displayed!

I need to work with a QMainWindow descendant because my real application uses menus, statusbar, and a toolbar. So it looks I got confused with PyQt's class hierarchy. Any hints?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

You only missed one step. You need to set a [`centralWidget`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget) to your QMainWindow. You can do this by adding this line to the end of your `__init__` method:

```
self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
```

This sets your tabs widget to the central widget utilizing [`setCentralWidget`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) and produces a Main Window that looks like this:

[image: Main Window]

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `self.tabs`widget as central widget in your class

```
class tabdemo(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
        super(tabdemo, self).__init__()
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1,"Form View")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2,"Matrix View")
        self.tab1UI()
        self.tab2UI()
        self.setWindowTitle("tab demo")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
```

Notice the last line of the code: **`self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)`**